# select form value and return unique id from database

Tags: javascript, php

I have an ajax search form field returning an address value from the database. I am trying to get the unique id of a selected address and display that value on a div called "demo". Any ideas?

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("ls_query");
        var adr = x.value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "address is:" +adr;

        }
    </script>
```

ls_query value is an address (123 whatever the street name...) lets say the unique ID is '5'. I need value 5 returned instead of the address.

Comment: what do you mean with unique id?

Comment: So return the ID instead of the address, no? Where is the ajax, PHP?

Comment: How you load the ls_query? This element have the id?

Comment: Yes Chris. Is it possible to create an onclick event using php instead of javascript? That way I can run the select statement right??

Comment: @CyberFla PHP generates your code and sends it to the browser. Once it is in the browser, you cannot do any more PHP, unless your javascript makes an ajax request BACK to the server, wherin you then do some more PHP. This is an essential thing you need to know.